# Flutter Why Shimmer loading effect doesn't work on IOS?

Tags: flutter

I follow [the flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/shimmer-loading) create a shimmer loading effect class like below

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

const _shimmerGradient = LinearGradient(
  colors: [
    Color(0xFFEBEBF4),
    Color(0xFFF00000),
    Color(0xFFEBEBF4),
  ],
  stops: [
    0.1,
    0.3,
    0.4,
  ],
  begin: Alignment(-1.0, -0.3),
  end: Alignment(1.0, 0.3),
  tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
);

class ShimmerLoading extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShimmerLoading({
    super.key,
    required this.isLoading,
    required this.child,
  });

  final bool isLoading;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ShimmerLoading> createState() => _ShimmerLoadingState();
}

class _ShimmerLoadingState extends State<ShimmerLoading> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!widget.isLoading) {
      return widget.child;
    }

    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) {
        return _shimmerGradient.createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

and i implement it on test screen.

```
test_screen.dart
class _TestScreenState extends BaseConsumerState<TestScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ...
            ShimmerLoading(
              isLoading: true,
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
           ...
  }
}
```

I tested it on the emulator.
It works on Android but doesn't work on IOS.
How can I make sure that will work on the real device?

IOS' screen
the black square is a shimmer loading effect.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Shimmer Package

[Package From here](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer)